# aws athena - cast as json don't return json object

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have a list of json objects (result attribute) as in the example :

```
    select result   from mytable limit 1
```

I get :

```
[{hop=1, error=null, result=[{x=null, from=192.168.0.1, rtt=0.378, ttl=64, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=192.168.0.1, rtt=0.314, ttl=64, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=192.168.0.1, rtt=0.303, ttl=64, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=2, error=null, result=[{x=null, from=71.120.7.1, rtt=8.135, ttl=254, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=71.120.7.1, rtt=0.769, ttl=254, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=71.120.7.1, rtt=0.761, ttl=254, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=3, error=null, result=[{x=null, from=100.41.136.160, rtt=5.583, ttl=253, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=100.41.136.160, rtt=1.749, ttl=253, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=100.41.136.160, rtt=1.805, ttl=253, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=4, error=null, result=[{x=*, from=null, rtt=null, ttl=null, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=null, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=*, from=null, rtt=null, ttl=null, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=null, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=*, from=null, rtt=null, ttl=null, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=null, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=5, error=null, result=[{x=null, from=140.222.239.91, rtt=3.121, ttl=251, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=140.222.239.91, rtt=2.984, ttl=251, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=140.222.239.91, rtt=3.0, ttl=251, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=6, error=null, result=[{x=*, from=null, rtt=null, ttl=null, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=null, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=*, from=null, rtt=null, ttl=null, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=null, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=*, from=null, rtt=null, ttl=null, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=null, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=7, error=null, result=[{x=null, from=4.69.153.150, rtt=100.718, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=4.69.153.150, rtt=100.748, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=4.69.153.150, rtt=100.708, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=8, error=null, result=[{x=null, from=212.73.203.18, rtt=101.694, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=212.73.203.18, rtt=101.954, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=212.73.203.18, rtt=101.721, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=9, error=null, result=[{x=null, from=193.171.23.41, rtt=101.096, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=193.171.23.41, rtt=101.132, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=193.171.23.41, rtt=101.115, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=10, error=null, result=[{x=null, from=193.170.114.242, rtt=101.884, ttl=56, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=40, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=193.170.114.242, rtt=101.695, ttl=56, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=40, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=193.170.114.242, rtt=100.881, ttl=56, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=40, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}]
```

I try to get this attribute as json object (without "=") so I can use the results in my application that take only json data.

I try the function cast `(myattribute as json)` :

```
select cast (result as json)  from mytable limit 1
```

But, I get :

```
[[1,null,[[null,"192.168.0.1",0.378,64,null,null,null,null,null,null,68,null,null,null,null],[null,"192.168.0.1",0.314,64,null,null,null,null,null,null,68,null,null,null,null],[null,"192.168.0.1",0.303,64,null,null,null,null,null,null,68,null,null,null,null]]],[2,null,[[null,"71.120.7.1",8.135,254,null,null,null,null,null,null,28,null,null,null,null],[null,"71.120.7.1",0.769,254,null,null,null,null,null,null,28,null,null,null,null],[null,"71.120.7.1",0.761,254,null,null,null,null,null,null,28,null,null,null,null]]],[3,null,[[null,"100.41.136.160",5.583,253,null,null,null,null,null,null,68,null,null,null,null],[null,"100.41.136.160",1.749,253,null,null,null,null,null,null,68,null,null,null,null],[null,"100.41.136.160",1.805,253,null,null,null,null,null,null,68,null,null,null,null]]],[4,null,[["*",null,null,null,"*",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],["*",null,null,null,"*",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],["*",null,null,null,"*",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]]],[5,null,[[null,"140.222.239.91",3.121,251,null,null,null,null,null,null,28,null,null,null,null],[null,"140.222.239.91",2.984,251,null,null,null,null,null,null,28,null,null,null,null],[null,"140.222.239.91",3.0,251,null,null,null,null,null,null,28,null,null,null,null]]],[6,null,[["*",null,null,null,"*",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],["*",null,null,null,"*",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],["*",null,null,null,"*",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]]],[7,null,[[null,"4.69.153.150",100.718,244,null,null,null,null,null,null,28,null,null,null,null],[null,"4.69.153.150",100.748,244,null,null,null,null,null,null,28,null,null,null,null],[null,"4.69.153.150",100.708,244,null,null,null,null,null,null,28,null,null,null,null]]],[8,null,[[null,"212.73.203.18",101.694,244,null,null,null,null,null,null,68,null,null,null,null],[null,"212.73.203.18",101.954,244,null,null,null,null,null,null,68,null,null,null,null],[null,"212.73.203.18",101.721,244,null,null,null,null,null,null,68,null,null,null,null]]],[9,null,[[null,"193.171.23.41",101.096,244,null,null,null,null,null,null,28,null,null,null,null],[null,"193.171.23.41",101.132,244,null,null,null,null,null,null,28,null,null,null,null],[null,"193.171.23.41",101.115,244,null,null,null,null,null,null,28,null,null,null,null]]],[10,null,[[null,"193.170.114.242",101.884,56,null,null,null,null,null,null,40,null,null,null,null],[null,"193.170.114.242",101.695,56,null,null,null,null,null,null,40,null,null,null,null],[null,"193.170.114.242",100.881,56,null,null,null,null,null,null,40,null,null,null,null]]]]
```

As you see, the keys are omitted ! 
Any help?

Comment: Would you please share your table definition?

Comment: @Hayat did you manage to fix this? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Hayat, what does `select typeof(result)   from mytable limit 1` return? It's not JSON, so let's figure out what is it.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen,Did you guys figure out a way to get the keys as well, if the underling row isnt a JSON.I have a similar problem [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64111630/construct-json-from-data-using-presto)

Comment: @Ram not sure i undersand the question, but if you want to influence project roadmap please file and issue https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/new or join the conversation https://prestosql.io/slack.html

Comment: @LuigiPlinge did you ever find a solution for this either?

Comment: solution is discussed here in detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75480722/how-can-i-get-result-in-json-format-from-aws-athena/75482611#75482611

Comment: alternate solution for this problem is discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75480722/how-can-i-get-result-in-json-format-from-aws-athena/75482611#75482611

Answer (score 2):

That's because it's stored as a ROW type field and not JSON. You can access the different keys by doing

`select field.key from table`

You can check more about it in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/rows-and-structs.html)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast varchar value

```
[{hop=1, error=null, result=[{x=null, from=192.168.0.1, rtt=0.378, ttl=64, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=192.168.0.1, rtt=0.314, ttl=64, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=192.168.0.1, rtt=0.303, ttl=64, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=2, error=null, result=[{x=null, from=71.120.7.1, rtt=8.135, ttl=254, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=71.120.7.1, rtt=0.769, ttl=254, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=71.120.7.1, rtt=0.761, ttl=254, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=3, error=null, result=[{x=null, from=100.41.136.160, rtt=5.583, ttl=253, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=100.41.136.160, rtt=1.749, ttl=253, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=100.41.136.160, rtt=1.805, ttl=253, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=4, error=null, result=[{x=*, from=null, rtt=null, ttl=null, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=null, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=*, from=null, rtt=null, ttl=null, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=null, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=*, from=null, rtt=null, ttl=null, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=null, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=5, error=null, result=[{x=null, from=140.222.239.91, rtt=3.121, ttl=251, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=140.222.239.91, rtt=2.984, ttl=251, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=140.222.239.91, rtt=3.0, ttl=251, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=6, error=null, result=[{x=*, from=null, rtt=null, ttl=null, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=null, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=*, from=null, rtt=null, ttl=null, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=null, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=*, from=null, rtt=null, ttl=null, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=null, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=7, error=null, result=[{x=null, from=4.69.153.150, rtt=100.718, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=4.69.153.150, rtt=100.748, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=4.69.153.150, rtt=100.708, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=8, error=null, result=[{x=null, from=212.73.203.18, rtt=101.694, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=212.73.203.18, rtt=101.954, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=212.73.203.18, rtt=101.721, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=68, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=9, error=null, result=[{x=null, from=193.171.23.41, rtt=101.096, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=193.171.23.41, rtt=101.132, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=193.171.23.41, rtt=101.115, ttl=244, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=28, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}, {hop=10, error=null, result=[{x=null, from=193.170.114.242, rtt=101.884, ttl=56, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=40, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=193.170.114.242, rtt=101.695, ttl=56, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=40, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}, {x=null, from=193.170.114.242, rtt=100.881, ttl=56, err=null, ittl=null, edst=null, late=null, mtu=null, size=40, flags=null, dstoptsize=null, hbhoptsize=null, icmpext=null}]}]
```

to JSON, because it's not well-formed JSON representation. E.g. the keys must be quoted and values separated with colons, like this: `{"hop":1, "error": null, "result": ...`

Comment: I think in the question, `result` is valid json, but what's posted is the way Athena formats the output. It should be possible to parse as json.

Comment: Could be. @LuigiPlinge let's clarify.