# How can I get result in JSON format from AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I want to get result in JSON format, below is the structure of object **obj**

```
UUID              string 
MobileCountryCode string 
UserState         []struct {
    Mobile    int64 
    IsNewUser bool  
}
```

when i do simple select of object from Athena via Redash:

```
select obj FROM table_name
```

getting output in this format:

```
 {uuid=UCLPKJWPZXH,mobile_country_code=,user_state=[{mobile=9988998899, is_new_user=false}]}
```

We can see clearly the output doesn't contain double quotes for json keys and has = instead of : to qualifier for proper json

I even tried casting it to json:

```
select CAST(obj AS JSON) AS json_obj FROM table_name
```

but i am getting only values without json keys like below:

```
["UCLPKJWPZXH","",[["9988998899",false]]]
```

But i want it to be like this **with json keys**

```
{"uuid":"UCLPKJWPZXH","mobile_country_code":"","user_state":[{"mobile":9988998899,"is_new_user":false}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Athena is based on Presto/Trino (engine v3 should use Trino functions) and in Trino `cast(... as json)` should work:

```sql
select cast(r as json)
from (values (1, CAST(ROW('UUID123', array[row(1, TRUE)]) AS ROW(UUID varchar, UserState array(row(Mobile int, IsNewUser boolean)))))) as t(id, r);
```

Output:

```
                             _col0
----------------------------------------------------------------
 {"uuid":"UUID123","userstate":[{"mobile":1,"isnewuser":true}]}
```

Try upgrading to v3 engine. If you are already using v3 engine or it does not work after upgrade or you can't upgrade - the only way is to convert `ROW` into `MAP`, because Presto treats `ROW`s as arrays ([docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html)):

> When casting from ROW to JSON, the result is a JSON array rather than a JSON object. This is because positions are more important than names for rows in SQL.

And converting row to map can be quite cumbersome:

```sql
select cast(
               map(array['UUID123', 'MobileCountryCode', 'UserState'],
                   array[
                        cast(r.UUID as json),
                        cast(r.MobileCountryCode as json),
                        cast(
                            transform(r.UserState,
                                e -> map(
                                    array['Mobile', 'IsNewUser'],
                                    array[cast(e.Mobile as json), cast(e.IsNewUser as json)]))
                            as json)
                        ])
           as json)
from (values (1, CAST(ROW('UUID123', 'US', array[row(1, TRUE)]) AS ROW (UUID varchar, MobileCountryCode varchar,
                                                                        UserState array(row(Mobile int, IsNewUser boolean)))))) as t(id, r);
```

Output:

```
                                           _col0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"MobileCountryCode":"US","UUID123":"UUID123","UserState":[{"IsNewUser":true,"Mobile":1}]}
```